# How to set PrintOut method to a single a4 page

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below, im trying to make my selection of cells print on one a4 page rather than spread across 6 in a command button that is on a sheet, can anyone point out what im doing wrong? I expected to be able to have a printing window like with saving a sheet or something like that, but this is all i can find. thanks a tonne for your help :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Sheets("Home").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$W$44"
    Sheets("Home").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    Sheets("Home").PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    Sheets("Home").PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
    Sheets("Home").PrintPreview (EnableChanges = True)
    'Sheets("Home").PrintOut (Preview = True)
End Sub
```

Ive looked for other some VBA online and looked up the pagesetup, but i cant seem to find what im after, the code above is the closest ive found, but it makes no difference to the printing process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the relevant parts of the code. Let me know if you still have any questions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()       
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = "$A$1:$W$44"
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With
        
        '~~> To fit text spanning in different pages change the view
        ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
        
        '~~> Extend the Horizontal Pagebreak to extreme right
        '~~> This mimics what you do when you are dragging the PgBrk
        If .HPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then _
        .HPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlDown, RegionIndex:=1
        
        '~~> Similarly extend the Vertical Pagebreak to extreme down
        If .VPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then _
        .VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
        
        .PrintPreview EnableChanges:=True
        
        '~~> Change the view back to normal
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    End With
End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

and the print preview

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: youre just incredible, thats absolutely amazing thankyou so much!!! above and beyond there mate, cheers an absolute tonne

Comment: Glad it worked. I did cover about [Page Setup and Printing](https://youtu.be/JW9EXjX3RxY) on my YouTube channel but this was something which was left out. I will include this in one of my future videos :)